# How do I change the Junk folder on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, spam

My mail provider puts spam into a folder called "Spam".  On my Mac, I've configured Mac Mail to use this folder when I use the "Move to Junk" action.  But if I try the same from the iPhone, it creates a folder called "Junk" and moves things there.  I don't want two different spam folders; I want to keep "Spam", not "Junk".

How do I change the folder that my iPhone uses to make it the same as my Mac?

Comment: And you have logged into the web interface from your mail provider and verified there is no setting there that will do that? I ask because most IMAP mail servers are configured at the server end when it comes to folder behavior.

Comment: I want to keep "Spam", not "Junk".  I originally got that the wrong way round in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers my question, above. *Have you* tried the web interface?

Comment: The reason I mention it is that it's my mail provider using "Spam" and my iPhone using "Junk", so it's the iPhone I need to change.  My mail provider does not host any configuration for my iPhone.